# Fonts in scrartcl

Tags: fonts, table-of-contents, koma-script

When I started using the `scrartcl` class all the fonts (section, title ...) were messed up. How can I get them back as they where when I used `article`? Do I have to set them all with `addtokomafont`?

Even if I do this, the sections in the tableofcontents are still using the wrong font.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The headings are far from being messed up. They are just tagged differently. And the [KOMA Script](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) manual tells you quite clearly how you can get what you want.

```
\documentclass[english]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalfont\bfseries}

\begin{document}
  \Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10):

Since KOMA-Script 3.20 the classes provided an option `egregdoesnotlikesansseriftitles` that deactivates all sans serif defaults of the KOMA-Script classes. With KOMA-Script 3.39 this option has been replaced by `sfdefaults` with inverse logic. So with

```
\documentclass[sfdefaults=false]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
  \title{Title}
  \author{Author}
  \maketitle
  \Blinddocument
  \begin{description}
    \item[An item]\blindtext
  \end{description}
\end{document}
```

you will see the same fonts for title and heading as with `article`.

The old option was a result of a comment of @egreg to [Why does KOMA-Script mix serifs and sans-serifs?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/289853).

There is also an option `emulatestandardclasses` to make `scrartcl` even more `article` look-alike.

Comment: For koma  v3.39 or newer there is now the class option `sfdefaults=false` instead of `egregdoesnotlikesansseriftitles`