# List of calling modes in ConTeXt document

Tags: context, context-modes

I need something in document like this

```
\listcallingmodes
```

which return the list of calling modes, that is, if I run

```
context --mode=mode1,mode2 file.tex
```

in `file.tex`:

```
\starttext

\startmode[a1]
This is mode a1
\stopmode

Hello

\listcallingmodes
\stoptext
```

which I would to get

```
Hellp

mode1 mode2
```

Note that in this file we could have other modes than calling modes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NEW ANSWER:**

If you only need those modes called via the command line, this task is easier. Since ConTeXt stores command line data in the `environment` namespace, let's take advantage of this:

```
\startluacode
local listofcalledmodes = function()
    local split = string.split
    local flag  = '^--c:mode='
    local concat = table.concat
    for _, v in pairs(environment.originalarguments) do
        if v:find(flag) then
            local w = split(v:gsub(flag, ""), ",")
            context(concat(w, " ")) 
            return  
        end
    end
    context("No modes set")
end

interfaces.implement{
    name   = "listofcalledmodes",
    public = true,
    actions = listofcalledmodes
}
\stopluacode
\starttext
\startTEXpage
My list of modes: \listofcalledmodes
\stopTEXpage
\stoptext
```

Compiling your file the following way (`159.tex` is my file):

```bash
context --mode=amode,anothermode,toomanymodes 159.tex
```

I get the following result:

[image]

**OLD ANSWER:**

I'll ask for a feature request to the mailing list so a proper macro is available. In the meantime, the following should do the work most of times. Since modes are registered at the TeX end with as command sequences named with a `mode>` prefix (in [core-env.mkiv and core-env.mkxl](https://source.contextgarden.net/tex/context/base/mkiv/core-env.mkiv)), we can look up at them in `tex.hashtokens` (related discussion [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/574587)). However, if I get you right, you don't want [system modes](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Modes#System_modes) (internal, marked with an asterisk), so they will be filtered out:

```
\startluacode
local function listofmodes()
    local s1, s2  = "^mode>[^%*]+", "^mode>"
    context.blank() -- change this ad libitum
    for _, v in pairs(tex.hashtokens()) do
        if v:find(s1) and tex.modes[v:gsub(s2, "")] then
            context(v:gsub(s2, ""))
            context.par() -- also change this if needed
        end
    end
end

interfaces.implement{
    name    = "listofmodes",
    public  = true,
    actions = listofmodes
}
\stopluacode
\starttext
Hi, there's a list of used modes: \listofmodes
\stoptext
```

However, you may need a workaround, setting `hash_extra=0` in some cases (issue discussed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/574607/tex-hashtokens-incomplete)), so you're warned.

[image]

Comment: Can you please put the reference of feature request to the mailing list?

Comment: I only get `mkiv` in my document and I run `context --mode=espa1,espa1a,espa2,espa2a,espa3,espa3a,espa4,espa4a --nonstopmode --noconsole --purgeall myfile.conTeXt`

Comment: @jairo-a-del-rio It does not work for me: ```\startluacode
local function listofmodes()
    local s1, s2  = "^mode>[^%*]+", "^mode>"
    context.blank() -- change this ad libitum
    for _, v in pairs(tex.hashtokens()) do
        if v:find(s1) and tex.modes[v:gsub(s2, "")] then
            context(v:gsub(s2, ""))
        end
    end
end

interfaces.implement{
    name    = "listofmodes",
    public  = true,
    actions = listofmodes
}
\stopluacode

\starttext

\startmode[a1]
Això és a1
\stopmode

Jols

\stoptext```

Comment: @jairo-a-del-rio I edit the original question. I hope this helps you

Comment: Testing new code, I get carriage return before `\listofcalledmodes`. Is there any way to just give a space *before* that: something like `foo amode anothermode ...` instead of `foo \n amode anothermode..."?

Comment: @HenriMenke Just for curiosity. Can you give an alternative answer? with `return`?

Comment: @somenxavier I put `par` (or `context.par()` in the Lua side) on purpose. You only need to remove it and change `goto done` by `return`. I'll edit my answer

Comment: I don't see `par` in your new code

Comment: @somenxavier Yeah, I removed it as it was starting a new paragraph. Isn't that what you're asking for? Please clarify so that I can help

Comment: Yes, Jairo. It's definitvely what I want.